# Send php session with javascript redirect after successful login

Tags: javascript, php, session, redirect

I am trying to build a login using php and dhtmlxform. My form info successfully submits to my login.php script to check credentials. If they are correct, a user session is created and the script sends the response back to the javascript in dhtmlxform. If the session is created, I set $session equal to true and get the response back to javascript. If the response equals 1, then I redirect the user to the landing page. If the response is not 1, I alert the response (containing the failure error). What I need to do is bring the actual $_SESSION info from the login.php script over with the redirect in javascript. How do I go about doing this?

All help is appreciated! Thank you!

MY CODE:

HTML/Javascript:

```
 <body>

 <div id="headerDiv">
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <h1>Welcome to the Scheduler</h1>

    <br/>
    <br/>

</div>

<div id="bodyDiv">


    <div id="login"></div>

    <br/>
    <br/>

</div>
<script>


    loginStructure = [
        {type:"settings", position:"label-top"},
        {type:"fieldset", name: "loginFieldset", label: "Login", width: 200, list: [
            {type: "input", name: "username", label: "Username: "},
            {type:"password", name: "password", label: "Password: "},
            {type:"button", name: "submit", width: 50, offsetTop: 20, offsetLeft: 55, value: "Submit"}

        ]}

    ];



    var myForm = new dhtmlXForm("login",loginStructure);

    myForm.attachEvent("onButtonClick",function(id){
        if(id=="submit"){
            myForm.send("login.php", "post", function(loader, response){
                if (response == 1) {
                    window.location.href="https://ltiws.com/scheduler/production_sched.php";
                } else {
                    alert(response);
                };
            });
        }
    });

</script>

</body>
```

My PHP Script:

```
<?php

include("inc.php");


if ((isset($_POST['username'])) and (isset($_POST['password']))) {

    $login = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

} else {
    echo "Credentials did not save. Please try again.";
}


$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);


if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    echo "There was a problem connecting to MySQL: (" . $conn->connect_errno . ") " . $conn->connect_error;
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM sched_users WHERE login = ? ORDER BY login LIMIT 1";

if (!($sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM sched_users WHERE login = ? ORDER BY login LIMIT 1"))) {
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $conn->errno . ") " . $conn->error;
}


if (!($sql->bind_param("s", $login))) {
    echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $sql->errno . ") " . $sql->error;
}


if (!$sql->execute()) {
    echo "Execute failed: (" . $sql->errno . ") " . $sql->error;
}


$res = $sql->get_result();


if ($res->num_rows === 0) {

    echo "No user record found.";

} else if (!(($res->num_rows === 1) or ($res->num_rows === 0))) {

    echo "Too many results returned.";

} else {

    $row = $res->fetch_array();

    $hash = $row['password'];

    if (password_verify($pass, $hash)) {

        session_start();

        $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
        $_SESSION['firstname'] = $row['firstname'];
        $_SESSION['lastname'] = $row['lastname'];
        $_SESSION['login'] = $row['login'];
        $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];
        $_SESSION['phone'] = $row['phone'];
        $_SESSION['company'] = $row['company'];
        $_SESSION['department'] = $row['department'];
        $_SESSION['admin'] = $row['admin'];
        $_SESSION['statusflag'] = $row['statusflag'];
        $_SESSION['revoked'] = $row['revoked'];

        if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
            $session = true;
            echo $session;
        } else {
            $session = false;
            echo $session;
        }


    } else {
        echo "The username or password does not match. Please try again.";
    }
}


$sql->close();
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: Send the session using javascript is not secure.. You should think in others ways to do that

Comment: To actually set the session you can use the backend (php). Javascript can be used just to redirect the page or things like that. So, check if the user have the access and then redirect to the login page where PHP will set the session and redirect to the end screen

Comment: Well I had first tried to redirect the user from the script side user header(). Ideally, I'd rather do that but it was redirecting the script instead of the parent page. Is it possible to use header() to redirect the parent page from the script side?

Comment: You can send a signal to the javascript just to say it can redirect the user, but just redirect